# Converting ref of member into the ref of struct in Rust

Tags: rust, reference

Let's say I have a struct:

```rust
struct A {
    num: i32
}
```

Here, is there a way to convert `&i32` into `&A`?

Could I implement some kind of associated function to `A` that runs the conversion?

(Will it be possible with multiple members also?)

Comment: In general, you cannot. Now, this really seems like [a XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I will edit and add some information. Thank you

Comment: I have just realized I can bring `&i32` as a member of `A` like `struct A<'a> {num: &'a i32}`. I posted such a silly question, but thank you for your reply!